# Don't know how to start the program

Tags: python

I am taking a python class and one of the question asks

> Write a Python function that returns `True` if `aString` is a palindrome (reads the same forwards or reversed) and `False` otherwise. Do not use Python's built-in `reverse` function or `aString[::-1]` to reverse strings.
>
> This function takes in a string and returns a boolean.
>
> ```
> def isPalindrome(aString):
>     '''
>     aString: a string
>     '''
> ```

I am not sure if this question is asking me to start a function or create a loop and then it breaks out of the loop when it is false.

Comment: I believe it's asking you to do both actually. You have to write the `isPalindrome` function. It'll probably have a loop in it since you are not allowed to use the built in helper function. On another note, this question is not really a good fit for [so] since it's less an actual programming question and more a question about understanding a programming question (if that makes any sense). Please take a look at the [help] section to learn what [*types*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) of questions are encouraged on [so].

Comment: Thank you i finally learn how to format the questions and codes

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify *how* to do it.  It simply wants you to write a function so that someone could say `isPalindrome(aString)` and get the right answer.  There are restrictions for how you can *reverse* the string, but it doesn't tell you how to write your function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure where your confusion is, but your assignment is to make a Python function, which you've already done, which can be called ("started"?) from elsewhere in your program. Given your limitations, your instructor probably wants you to use a loop inside your `isPalindrome` function. A good approach would indeed be to:

> create a loop and then it breaks out of the loop when it is false

Good luck!

Comment: Actually got the question correct thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the desire of the teacher, you can do a few things.

- Pure and simple string. "Racecar" will fail, but "racecar" will not because "R" != "r"
- Case-insensitive. "Racecar" will pass. "No, it can assess an action." will fail.
- Don't count spaces/punctuation. "No, it can assess an action." will pass

First one:

```
def isPalindrone(aString):
    return aString == aString[::-1]
```

Second one:

```
def isPalindrone(aString):
    return aString.lower() == aString[::-1].lower()
```

Third one:

```
def isPalindrone(aString):
    aString = filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), aString)
    return aString.lower() == aString[::-1].lower()
```

Using the third one as the standard, since it is likely the best, we can create a recursive method that does not use [::-1] or reversed:

```
def reverseString(aString):
    if len(aString) <= 1:
        return aString
    else
        return isPalindrone(aString[1:] + aString[0])

def isPalindrone(aString):
    aString = filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), aString)
    return aString.lower() == reverseString(aString).lower()
```

This still uses slicing, so if you absolutely have to do it without that, you can do something like:

```
def isPalindrone(aString):
    aString = filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), aString)
    original = aString
    aString = ''.join([aString[i] for i in xrange(len(aString)-1, -1, -1)])
    return aString.lower() == original.lower()
```

Does this answer your questions?

Comment: Although correct the question explicitly states "Do not use Python's built-in reverse function or aString[::-1]". Edwin just needs to think of another way to reverse a string.

Answer (score 0):

I actually realize what the question was asking 
if you read carefully i was suppose to do a Palindrome without the reverse function and reverse string so I did `aString[-1-i]` which also reversed it.
Thanks for the the other ways to do palindrone.